# Port go AES Encrypt function to node.js

Tags: node.js, go, encryption

Im trying to port a go program (https://github.com/McKael/samtv) that can control samsung TVs via the "SmartView" API to node.js

In the program is a ["AES Encrypt" function](https://github.com/mStirner/samtv/blob/9f25793be2d4332107d479ae4b35f818cfdb347f/aes.go#L31) that i have trouble with porting to node.

```golang
func (s *SmartViewSession) aesEncrypt(plaindata []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    //logrus.Debugf("aesEncrypt(%#v) : '%s'", plaindata, string(plaindata))
    //logrus.Debugf("session ID:  %d", s.sessionID)
    //logrus.Debugf("session key: '%x'\n  %v", string(s.sessionKey), s.sessionKey)

    // Create cipher block
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(s.sessionKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    bs := block.BlockSize()
    //logrus.Debugf("block size: %d", bs)

    // Add padding
    padding := bs - len(plaindata)%bs
    padtext := bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(padding)}, padding)
    //logrus.Debugf("padding: %d byte(s)", padding)
    plaindata = append(plaindata, padtext...)

    // Encrypt
    ciphertext := make([]byte, len(plaindata))
    for cipherrange := ciphertext; len(plaindata) > 0; {
        block.Encrypt(cipherrange, plaindata[:bs])
        plaindata = plaindata[bs:]
        cipherrange = cipherrange[bs:]
    }

    //logrus.Debugf("ciphertext: %#v", ciphertext)
    return ciphertext, nil
}
```

The problem im facing right now is, i dont know what algorythim is used, or where the "initial vector" is coming from i need to specify in my node.js function:

```js
const SESSION_KEY = "59e8ca4b09f2a19ab5421cf55d604c7c";

var aesEncrypt = ((val, algo = "aes-256-cbc") => {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algo, SESSION_KEY, IV);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(val, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
});
```

Sould i use `crypto.createCipher(...)` instead? But its deprecated and have also the feeling that the padding stuff is important.

I have absolutely no clue about encryption.
Any hint is welcome.

NOTE: In the go function, `s.sessionKey` is the same value as in node.js the `SESSION_KEY = "59e8ca4b09f2a19ab5421cf55d604c7c"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go code applies AES in ECB mode with PKCS#7 padding. The AES variant is *implicitly* derived from the keysize, e.g. AES-128 for a 16 bytes key. The ciphertext is returned as `[]byte`.

In the NodeJS code, the AES variant is *explicitly* specified, along with the mode, e.g. `aes-128-ecb`. The ECB mode does not apply an IV, so it must be specified as `null` in `createCipheriv()`. As padding PKCS#7 (default) is used. The ciphertext can be returned as `Buffer`, which is closest to `[]byte`.

The posted key `59e8ca4b09f2a19ab5421cf55d604c7c` looks like a hex encoded key, which is hex decoded 16 bytes large and thus corresponds to AES-128. The hex decoding can be achieved in Go with the *encoding/hex* package, e.g. with `hex.DecodeString("59e8ca4b09f2a19ab5421cf55d604c7c")`.

Example for a NodeJS code that uses AES-128 (16 bytes key) in ECB mode and PKCS#7 padding:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');

const SESSION_KEY = Buffer.from("59e8ca4b09f2a19ab5421cf55d604c7c", "hex");

var aesEncrypt = ((val, algo = "aes-128-ecb") => {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algo, SESSION_KEY, null);
    return Buffer.concat([cipher.update(val, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);
});

var ciphertext = aesEncrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
console.log(ciphertext.toString('base64')); // T/uQforseVFkY93mqwpwCGVVnEFDTT5Gle8a8XUxCfOXCfYUo3uCJ/nwzCIJ9xqf
```

The Go code gives the same result using the same key (hex decoded) and plaintext and with Base64 encoding of the ciphertext.

For completeness: The key could also be UTF-8 encoded and would then result in a 32 bytes key, e.g. with `key := []byte("59e8ca4b09f2a19ab5421cf55d604c7c")` in the Go code and `const SESSION_KEY = Buffer.from("59e8ca4b09f2a19ab5421cf55d604c7c", "utf-8")` in the NodeJS code. In the NodeJS code, additionally `aes-256-ecb` must be applied. Ultimately, the key specification must provide information about which encoding to use.

---

Note that the ECB mode is insecure. Nowadays, authenticated encryption is usually used, e.g. via GCM mode.

Comment: Thank you very much. You explained it very well. +1